# How to select only numeric type of ccolumn names in sql server

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Currently I am working with a table in sql server

I want to select numeric datatype columns from table

I am using query now but it was showing all column names with datatypes

```
SELECT column_name as [Columname], data_type as [Data_Type] FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Table_name';


ExTable:
ID       Customername     Profit      Sales      Country     state
1        Paul             10          25         INDIA        AP
2        John             5           20         USA          NY
3        Prasanth         6           25         INDIA        TN
```

This is the table but i want to get only `ID`,`Profit`,`Sales` with their datatypes

Please let me know the query

Answer (score 1):

Extend your `WHERE` to include the column names?

```
SELECT c.[name] AS [Columname],
       ct.[name] AS [Data_Type]
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'Table_name'
  AND c.[name] IN ('ID','Profit','Sales');
```

Or do you mean...?

```
SELECT c.[name] AS [Columname],
       ct.[name] AS [Data_Type]
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'Table_name'
  AND ct.[name] IN ('tinyint','smallint','int','bigint','decimal','numeric','float');
```

That list is not exhaustive. For example you have `smallmoney`, `money` and `real` datatypes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT s.name AS 'schema', ts.name AS TableName,
    c.name AS column_name, c.column_id,   SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS DatatypeSchema,
    t.name AS Datatypename, t.is_user_defined, t.is_assembly_type, c.is_nullable,
    c.max_length, c.PRECISION, c.scale
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ts ON ts.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = ts.schema_id
    ORDER BY s.name, ts.name, c.column_id
```

Use where clause to filter results according to your requirement.